# Syntax of Cells.offset.value

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I have a few lines of code, and I don't know why they don't work.

```
  Dim strValSumMonth As String 
  strValSumMonth = "=SUMIF(" & Cells(i, j).Resize(, 4).Address(False, False) & ";" & Chr(34) & "OK" & Chr(34) & ";" & Range(strAdresseOKpasOk).Resize(, 4).Address(False, False) & ")"

 Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 5).Value = strValSumMonth
```

The value `strValSUmMonth` is for example `"=SUMIF(Z3:AC3;"OK";Z34:AC34)"`

The bug here is in the last code line.

Any help please ?

Comment: Change the `;` to `,` in your formula string, vba is very American-English centered and therefore needs to use the `,` instead.

Comment: Or use `FormulaLocal` instead of `Value`

Comment: i used formulalocal and it works perfectly